# How to know/fetch the column name of user_ by default table of liferay

Tags: mysql, liferay-6

I already ask lots of questions some time questions are really silly or annoyed one sorry for those questions. 
 Now again I have a question that how we can fetch the column name of user_ table which is one of the default table present in the liferay lportal database. May be this question is also silly, please forgive me and please reply I am new in liferay. I am using mysql 5 and liferay 6.1.
Thanks a lot to all members.
asif aftab

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for this-

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='yourdatabasename' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='yourtablename';
```

Or alternatively:

```
SHOW columns FROM tableName;
```

Comment: First thanks for your answer. Here I want to know the column name of liferay default table name user_. I have to write the code in my action class in java to fetch that table column name. I used mysql database. as back end process but we do not write the above statement directly and thanks again for your reply